# SelectionChangedEventHandler for a TabControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and am having issues with creating the event handler for changing tabs in a TabControl. In short, I do not understand how to find the previously selected TabItem's index and newly selected TabItem's index associated with the event.

Here is the code that I have tried so far:

```
private void primaryFilterChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Source is TabControl && IsLoaded) {
            int previous_index = (e.RemovedItems[0] as TabItem).TabIndex;
            int current_index = (e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem).TabIndex;
    ...
    }
}
```

but I realize now that "TabIndex" does not refer to what I think it does, instead referring to the order of focus items get when using the Tab key.

I know I can use `tabcontrol.SelectedIndex`to get the new index, but I need the previous one as well for other functions. Many thanks!

EDIT: The workaround I've used is creating my own "selectedTab" integer which is updated at the end of the event handler, but I was looking for something more elegant than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the old index like:

```
var tabControl = e.Source as TabControl;
var oldTabItem = e.RemovedItems[0] as TabItem;
var oldIndex = tabControl.Items.IndexOf(oldTabItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

A TabCOntrol is WPF inherits from  [Selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.aspx), so all you have to it hook up the [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) events handler, and it will have a list of AddedItems/RemovedItems. These will have what you want

For example suppose you have this

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabSelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
....
....
....
....
</TabControl>
```

When you would have some code behind like this

```
void TabSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var removedItems = args.RemovedItems;
    var addedItems = args.AddedItems;
}
```

Comment: Right, I understand that. I took it one step too short though, and forgot to use tabControl.Items.IndexOf to get the associated index, which is mainly what I'm interested in. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Well actually if you were doing things really properly you would use MVVM and expose an IEnumerable<SomeViewModel> and then use DataTemplates or use PRISM or whatever, and maybe use ICollectionView interface to deal with selection changes. But keeping to code behind sounds like you are now sorted

Comment: To be completely honest, I'm still a beginner to C# and don't really know what all of that entails. I'll look into it. Thank you.